# dc.js - how to get the average of a column in data set

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have this below data.

```
col1    col2    value
a   01/01/14    10
a   01/01/14    35
a   01/01/14    68
a   01/01/14    21
a   01/01/14    24
b   01/01/14    26
b   01/01/14    35
b   01/01/14    39
b   01/01/14    87
c   01/01/14    25
c   01/01/14    63
c   01/01/14    11
c   01/01/14    25
c   01/01/14    35
```

If I wanted to take the sum of col1. I could do it by using `col1Dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.value })`. If I need the count i can replace sum with count.

But I'm here loooking for average. So to that. I need to take sum of col1 and count of col1.

Any idea how can i divide and get the average?

Please help. Stuck in this for almost 3 days.

Comment: How about getting the sum and the count and then the average is sum/count?

Comment: How can I do it with `dc.js`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the [group.reduce(add, remove, initial)](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-group_reduce) method, like:

```
var col1DimTotal = col1Dim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  ++p.count;
  p.total += v.value;
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  --p.count;
  p.total -= v.value;
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {count: 0, total: 0};
}
```

Because you're using dc.js, you'll need to use [chart.valueAccessor](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#valueaccessorvalueaccessorfunction) method to use the average in your charts, like:

```
chart.valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value.count > 0 ? p.value.total / p.value.count : 0; });
```

Comment: Also can you please let me know how can i draw the `x-axis` label if the I wanted it to be on `col1`. Ex : in the `x-axis` instead date i would require 'a,b,c,d`.

Comment: Any chance you could post some code to present some context? I'm having difficulty understanding your question, given that your dimension/group choice should give you x-axis labels already like a,b,c,d.

Comment: @davidshinn : Great answer david, I'm using exactly this code, but not able to plot the graph and getting random/junk data on console. It would be great if you could have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188115/dc-and-crossfilter-calculating-percentage-within-records