# Crossfilter and dc.js mean value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have this data set:

```
tick    ID    Name    val1    val2    val3    val4
0       1     Name1    0.7    0.1       0.2    0.1
1       2     Name2    0.8    0.1       0.1    0.1
2       3     Name3    0.4    0.1       0.2    0.3
3       4     Name4    0.6    0.1       0.2    0.1
4       1     Name1    0.7    0.1       0.2    0.1
5       2     Name2    0.8    0.1       0.1    0.1
6       3     Name3    0.4    0.1       0.2    0.3
7       4     Name4    0.6    0.1       0.2    0.1
```

I already visualized everything with crossfilter and dc.js, except one diagram. I want the mean value of the column val1, val2, val3 and val4.

[image]

I have visualized this map with dc.js alread. The **ID** in the data is a segement in the image. The ticks are rounds, for instance the object with id 1 at tick 2 has the values 0.7, 0.1, 0.2 and 0.1. So the mean data should be connected to the segments. For instance when only the blue object with ID 1 is selected it should show the mean of the current selection:

```
tick    ID    Name    val1    val2    val3    val4
0       1     Name1    0.7    0.1       0.2    0.1
4       1     Name1    0.7    0.1       0.2    0.1
```

If I select a second object with ID 2, it should show the mean value of the both segments:

[image]

```
tick    ID    Name    val1    val2    val3    val4
0       1     Name1    0.7    0.1       0.2    0.1
1       2     Name2    0.8    0.1       0.1    0.1
4       1     Name1    0.7    0.1       0.2    0.1
5       2     Name2    0.8    0.1       0.1    0.1
```

Maybe I can show then the mean values of the two object in an pie chart. Where I can see the mean of the four classes val1, val2, val3 and val4. So I want to set them in relation like:

```
Sum val1 3
Sum val2 0.4
Sum val3 0.6
Sum val4 0.4

Sum all 4.4
```

So the classes would have the following size on the pie chart:

```
val1 3/4.4 = 0.68 = 68 percent
val2 0.4/4.4 = 0.090 = 9 percent
val3 ...
val4 ...
```

[image]

How can I accomplish this, because this was the only visualization that didn't worked.

Comment: This question could be helpful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519856/dc-js-how-to-get-the-average-of-a-column-in-data-set

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I checked the solution from the link but there is a problem with that. In the solution he uses the first row to define the dimension, which is in my case val1, val2.... But the problem is I don't have these values in the columns they are only in the first row. Is there a solution without reorganize the data?

Comment: If you can I think the best solution is to reorganize the data. I don't currently know of another way to do it, but maybe you can wait for others to comment/answer

Comment: I'm confused why this is not just taking four sums and four averages, just slightly more complicated than the answer @Ben linked. But then, your example output doesn't show any averages at all, so I'm doubly confused what you're trying to do

Comment: Maybe you mean that it's aggregated okay and you just need to turn the columns into group values with a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I added above an example which shows what I want to archive. I added the example after the second segmented picture where you can see the calculation. I want to take the sum of each column. Then sum all columns and devide each sum of the columns with the total sum, which gives the percentage of each row.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny how many different ways people explain how their data is structured and the result they need. Even with great detail explanation sometimes the message doesn't come across. Anyway I heard this post as being similar to my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926158/dc-charts-average-using-2-different-fields). Gordon suggested I use [reductio](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio).
However I dug into some other posts I ended up using the add remove initial methods. 
I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rickdg/dfhpx27L/) that gives you the percent per name. I would like to know from others more skilled with DC if this is being done correctly, or not.

```
   var data = d3.csv.parse( d3.select("pre#data").text() );     
            data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.tick = +d.tick
            d.id = +d.ID;
            d.name = d.Name;
            d.val1 = +d.val1;
            d.val2 = +d.val2;
            d.val3 = +d.val3;
            d.val4 = +d.val4;
        });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but I want to show on the x axis the val1, val2, val3 and val4 and not the name. On the y axis should be shown the relative values of the 4 groups val1, val2, val3 and val4.

Comment: I eneded up changing the data structure that it is not so flat.